# Unable to process date from firebase in angular 6

Tags: json, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
 this.qS = this.afDatabase.list('path', ref => {
    return ref.limitToLast(1000);
  }).snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
    return changes.map(c => ({ key1: c.payload.key,value1:c.payload.val() }));
  });
  this.qS.subscribe(values => {
    let count: number = Object.keys((values)).length;
    for(let i=0;i<count;i++){
           let const2:number=Object.keys(values[i].value1).length;  // is 3
           for(let j=0;j<const2;j++){
              console.log( values[i].value1[j]);//this line gives undefined why and How to get value from this?
            }
    }
  });
```

values[i].value1 =>[object Object]

```
JSON.stringify(values[i].value1)=>
    {"-LJ2PhylTGjo1Li6QxP4":{"dtime":{"befor_":0,"dates":"04-Aug-2018","from_t":14,"fullDetails":"Between 2 PM to 6 PM on 7-08-2018","id":1,"mDay":"7","mMonth":"08","mYear":"2018","to_t":18,"weak":2},"lan":0,"lon":0},"-LJ2PtF3X9OaH-5Lv982":{"dtime":{"befor_":0,"dates":"04-Aug-2018","from_t":14,"fullDetails":"Between 2 PM to 6 PM on 7-08-2018","id":1,"mDay":"7","mMonth":"08","mYear":"2018","to_t":18,"weak":2},"lan":0,"lon":0},"-LJIQjbtU7Ryz-gUcxRF":{"dtime":{"befor_":0,"dates":"07-Aug-2018","from_t":14,"fullDetails":"Between 2 PM to 6 PM on 8-08-2018","id":1,"mDay":"8","mMonth":"08","mYear":"2018","timestampCreated":{"timestamp":1533629365655},"to_t":18,"weak":3},"lan":0,"lon":0}}
```

Now we need to read fullDetails date from above string . How to do it in typescript ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `for in loop` as it is a Object:

```
for (var j in values[i].value1) {
    console.log(values[i].value1[j].dtime.fullDetails)
}
```

Comment: How to get -LJ2PhylTGjo1Li6QxP4 ?  I tried values[i].value1[j].key but it is undefined

Comment: Here `j` is  `-LJ2PhylTGjo1Li6QxP4`